# how can i highlight snippets(python or js) without highlight.css in a static page(no script, no css link)

Tags: html, css, highlight

I want to highlight a snippet in a page, but no script or css file can be used.
so I need to render snippet from A to B:
A:

> if platform.system() == "Linux":

B:

```html
<p><span style="color:red">if</span>&nbsp;<span style="color:green;">platform.system()</span>&nbsp;==&nbsp;"<span style="color:blue">Linux</span>":
```

Comment: So? what's the problem?

Comment: 3Q, I found a tool named "hightlight" which could highlight my code to html.  http://www.andre-simon.de/index.php

Comment: Good for you.. I guess.. Buy the way, you can use http://hilite.me/ online.